# How to include library files while creating jar files

Tags: java

How to include JOGL.jar and Gluegen-rt.jar in the java project? I have included these external jars in the eclipse, but when I try to create a Jar file of the project, the JAR file does not exceute. It says That JOGL.jar is missing.

How can I include these libraries? Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: kind of duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179024/adding-a-jar-to-an-eclipse-java-library

Comment: @Kumar, why such low accept-rate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ***How can I include these libraries? Any suggestions are welcome.***

Either you distribute multiple jar-files, and make sure the referenced jar-files are mentioned in the classpath in the manifest of your application.

However, since you say "include" I suspect you want to "merge" the jar files into a single jar file. In that case you need to merge the jars using software such as [OneJar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/) or [FatJar](http://fjep.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Additional possibility with Maven: Create a [jar-with-dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html#jar-with-dependencies).

Comment: If the OP is using Eclipse, he/she should have a "make fat-jar" option when right-clicking the project.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the jar is there in the classpath.