# how to get geolocator-java into eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, geocoding

I am trying to get this:
http://code.google.com/p/geocoder-java/
into eclipse to work with the geocoder API. I have the SVN plugin already installed and now I am wondering what I have to do to get it into one of my projects so that I can use it as a library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Source](http://code.google.com/p/geocoder-java/source/checkout) page of the project:

> Non-members may check out a read-only working copy anonymously over HTTP.
>
> svn checkout http://geocoder-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ geocoder-java-read-only

Add the geocoder directory to your list of SVN directories and use the provided userid and a null password.

Comment: yes, I already have it in my eclipse project. But I am not sure what I have to do to actually use it. Right now I added the SVN directory with all sub-directories into one of my existing projects. But now what? If I make a new main class and paste the example form the first page of source site it just sayis that the packages don´t match and I can´t import the necessary classes.

Comment: @Kris: Use Eclipse to make a jar file from the geocoder project, and include that geocoder jar file in your project classpath.

Answer (score 0):

If you already downloaded and built the .jar file, you just have to add it as an external library.

Similar to [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179024/adding-a-jar-to-an-eclipse-java-library)