# Create a collection like key value pair with duplicate keys?

Tags: java

consider as,

```
HashMap<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
```

i want store like,

```
map.put(1, "Val-1");
map.put(2, "Val-2");
map.put(1, "Val-3");
map.put(1, "Val-4");
map.put(3, "Val-5");
.
.
. it goes like this
```

when I give a it should give all the values associated with a key. How can I solve it. Not one HashMap if you know other possibilities please to tell me

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do i import multimap for java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14925329/how-do-i-import-multimap-for-java)

Answer (score 6):

You can use a `HashMap<Integer,List<String>>`.

You group all the values sharing the same key in a list.

```
HashMap<Integer,List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
l.add("Val-1");
l.add("Val-3");
l.add("Val-4");
map.put(1, l);
l = new ArrayList<>();
l.add("Val-2");
map.put(2, l);
l = new ArrayList<>();
l.add("Val-5");
map.put(3, l);
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java, `Map`s do not allow duplicate keys. So, to associate multiple values you'll need to assign every key a `List` instead. Also, notice how I'm using an *interface* type on the *reference* side.

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> map = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();
```

Now you just have to create your own `put()` version that **adds** to these `List`s instead.

```
public void add(Integer key, String val) {
    List<String> list = map.get(key);
    if (list == null) {
        list = new ArrayList<String>();
        map.put(key, list);
    }
    list.add(val);
}
```

Here's how you would add and display multiple values

```
add(1, "one");
add(2, "two");
add(2, "three");

for(Map.Entry<Integer, List<String>> entry: map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue());
}
```

***Output :***

```
1 = [one]
2 = [two, three]
```