# how to add ojdbc14.jar to maven project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, jar, ojdbc

How can I add the ojdbc14.jar file to a maven project in eclipse? In other posts, there is a mention of a installing the jar into the local repository. However, I cannot install maven on this machine and eclipse is the only way in.

Thanks.

Comment: and how are you compiling your project, because maven project need dependencies that are in remote or local repository?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding a JAR to an Eclipse Java library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179024/adding-a-jar-to-an-eclipse-java-library)

Comment: I am able to build the project and create the shaded jar with the rest of the dependencies mentioned in the pom.xml through eclipse. It is only the ojdbc.jar that gets excluded as I could not add it to pom.xml. Hence want to see if there is any other work around.