# Error in running Maven-dependency jar is not found

Tags: java, maven

I'm new to Maven and would like to build a maven project from [This link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-hadoop). I installed maven and when I run command 'mvn clean install' it proceeds but finally gives me an error message that class `JsonSerDe` in not found. This class exists in one of the dependency jar files but my question is why maven doesn't automatically download that dependency jar file? How can I solve this problem?

The other question is how can I use maven as

```xml
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
 <artifactId>azure-documentdb-hadoop</artifactId>
 <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Read "Maven in 5 minutes" 
https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html. Very helpful!

Comment: Maven is usually very good about finding and downloading dependencies. Are you set up to point to maven central? Are you behind a firewall?  Perhaps you need to configure your settings.xml

Comment: As @azurefrog mentioned, please verify your settings.xml and firewall settings. Immediate alternative can be, get the jar externally through download and can place in the local repository(all downloaded jars stay here) where you are referring to. This is ok, when you have issues with one or two jars. However as long term solution, please identify the other options mentioned.

Comment: I didn't rouch the setting.xml and it is the default values. How can I locate the local repository? should I just copy the missing jar file there?

Comment: I don't think that there is any firewall problem because it can download all the dependency files, except one!

Answer (score 0):

This is because the hive implementation is dependent on the open source 
[hive serde](https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde)
which is not available in maven.

You need to add it as a dependency to your project to get to build, there are two ways to add it to project:

1) Adding the jar to your local maven repo
[Adding jar to local maven repo](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/examples/specific-local-repo.html) and add the local repo to your pom.xml file using this [Add repository to your pom.xml](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html)
You can get the jar from here [json serde releases](http://www.congiu.net/hive-json-serde/)

2) Adding the jar as just a dependency jar to the project using eclipse without involving maven [Add jar as dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179024/adding-a-jar-to-an-eclipse-java-library)