# How to enable Yandex Translate API?

Tags: java, yandex

this may sound like a noob question, but it is a big problem for me. I have a file called yandex-translator-java-api-master.zip, and I tried adding that as an external JAR to my eclipse project, but the code wouldn't work; It wouldn't let me import.

This error comes up when i try to import "Translate"
Translate cannot be resolved
6 quick fixes available:
Create class, create constant, fix proj. setup...etc, etc.

How do i use this??? Where is the .jar i am supposed to import?

Comment: And you can not just "connect as a library?" This is usually right click on .jar in the project.

Comment: I don't have that option

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/179097/2413972

Comment: Don't have a library, or I can't figure out where it is. here are the files, maybe you can help me(again)?https://github.com/rmtheis/yandex-translator-java-api Thanks, and sorry for being so noob

Comment: Add the normal output error.

Comment: My answer for this question on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45008632/2946353

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zip` archive is not the same thing as `jar`. First, extract `jar` from zip archive and then add it as dependency. Then you'll be able to import.

UPD:
looking closely, I suppose you downloaded that archive from GitHub (or another VCS) and it's just sources of a library. You can not add it as a dependency, but you can, for example, just paste this code in your project's `/src/main/`. This is an *easy* solution. If you want to make things the right way, you can 
a) Search for a compiled library
b) Create a module from downloaded sources and add it as dependency

Answer (score 1):

Download this file:
[image]

And established it as a library.
Instruction is in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/179097/2413972).

Comment: Ok, i got the jar and added it, but the code still gives the same error i mentioned above in my question.